# Partitioning data between multiple schemas in hibernate/spring

Tags: spring, hibernate, annotations, schema, partitioning

Our application distinguishes between data for a particular "user" (actually a legal entity, but we'll call it user for simplicity) and data which is shared between all users. It is a requirement that user data be held in a separate schema for each user. So there is data which is common and shared in a schema which can be accessed by all users, and a number of schemas each of which can only be accessed by the user to which it relates. These user schemas would each contain the same set of tables so we might have something like USERA.ACCOUNT, USERB.ACCOUNT (and so on), and SHARED.PRODUCT in the common schema. We have achieved this and produced something which meets the requirements quite nicely by specifying @Table(schema="SHARED") for the entity types representing common data. We don't specify the schema on the "user" entity types - the choice of schema to look in is left up to the DAO. We have one DAO per user, each configured to use the appropriate user schema and selected on the basis of the user "context" associated with any given operation.

So far so good - but the name of the shared schema is now hard coded into the entity class files for the shared data types. And because it's in an annotation it is compiled into them. This is no good for us since typically when deploying on client sites we find that the client DBA wishes to dictate schema names but we do not wish to have to recompile in order to achieve this. Even worse, at a client site we would typically have multiple systems for different purposes with different schema names (PROD, UAT, etc etc) and to do this using multiple recompiled copies of the same system would be madness.

I have not been able to find a way to override the schema defined in the annotation. Is anyone aware of a way to achieve this? I have tried porting our system from using hibernate directly (SessionFactory etc) to JPA (EntityManagers and so forth) as this in principal allows the schema attribute in the annotation to be overridden by an entry in the ORM.xml, but there appears to be a world of problems with using JPA/JTA/Spring whereby operations in the transaction lifecycle such as flush no longer happen as you would expect, so I backed away from that.

Any suggestions would be most welcome ...

Answer (score 0):

You have SEVERAL options..
You can use dynamic routing (check spring documentation, but there are a LOT of post on stackoverflow as well). That's the best fit for your solution..
Basically you have SEVERAL connection configured and based on some criteria spring will route your queries to One or the other connection (schema) based on some criteria. Basically same bean, fetched by a different schema based on need.

Other options would be to have multiple bean with same structure each with an entity manager and transaction manager differently configured in the applicationcontext but really this is better suited for a different situation from yours..

Frankly the first solution i think it's simple enough and the best fit to your need..
Check this link for an example or check spring doc, it rally helper me at the time.
[tutorial](http://howtodoinjava.com/2013/12/28/spring-3-2-5-abstractroutingdatasource-example/)